# Transactions fails due to "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: java, mysql

When trying to update a certain table, it fails with the exception of: "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction".
Some info: I have two tables, profile and profile_units. ID is the primary key of the profile table, and ID is part of a primary key in profile_units, and is also a foreign key to ID in profile.
Whan I call saveProfileChanges, the updateAllFields method succeeds, but the addStmt.executeUpdate(); in handleActivityUnitsChanges fails with the above exception.
I use MySQL v5.0 for a data base. What am I doing wrong?

I try to execute the following code:

```
    public static Profile saveProfileChanges(Profile profile, List unitsToAdd)
        throws Exception
{
    Connection con = null;
    try
    {
        con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        updateAllFields(con, profile);

        handleActivityUnitsChanges(con, profile, unitsToAdd);

        con.commit();
        return profile;
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectionManager.closeConnection(con);
    }
}

private static void handleActivityUnitsChanges(Connection con, Profile profile, List<ActivityUnit> unitsToAdd) throws Exception
{
    PreparedStatement addStmt = null;

    try
    {
        for (ActivityUnit currentUnitToAdd : unitsToAdd)
        {
            String sqlStatement = "insert into profile_units (ID, ActivityUnit) values (?, ?)";
            addStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);

            addStmt.setLong(1, profile.getId());
            addStmt.setLong(2, currentUnitToAdd.getId());

            System.out.println(sqlStatement);

            addStmt.executeUpdate();
            addStmt.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        con.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectionManager.closeStatement(addStmt);
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///someproject", "a", "a");

    con.setAutoCommit(false);

    return con;
}
```

Comment: `insert into profile_units )ID, ActivityUnit) values (?, ?)` - Is this real code?

Comment: no, it should have been (ID, ActivityUnit) values (?, ?)

Comment: Have you got the table locked by a different process? By a sql tool for example?

Comment: How do you run this code? Do you have any other concurrent transactions?

Comment: I don't think there is any other process running - To make sure I killed the MYSql service, restarted it and ran it again with the same (bad) results.
I run this code from a different class, and run only this code. I don'y think any other concurrent transaction exists. Is there a way to check? (I tried looking in the administration panel in MYSQL but havn't found anything useful).

Comment: Not sure that this'll cure your problem, but you should prepare your statement outside the loop. You don't need to prepare it each time, and you will be decreasing the performance of your application by doing so ). Preparing causes the execution plan to be executed once, you just then substitute your values in, saving that calculation on subsequence iterations

Comment: you are right that this is a good thing in general, but the lock occurs the first time I try to execute the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured out what the problem was - In updateAllFields (which for some odd reason i didn't showed here) I obtained a new connection, so the two transactions got mixed.
Thanks for the help anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at innodb_lock_wait_timeout variable. It is - *the timeout in seconds an InnoDB transaction may wait for a lock before being rolled back*. The default value is 50 seconds, you could increase this value; but I think is better to rewrite loop-inserts code or to optimize something.

As a variant - try to run less insert statements in transaction.
To speed up transaction you could use multiple inserts, e.g. - 'INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2) VALUES(1,'text1'),(2,'text2')...;'

Comment: The thing is, I run only *1* update in the table profile, to a signle record with the key 12 (and it is the *only* record in that table), and immidietly after I run the insert command in the table profile_units. It shouldn't take 50 seconds to update and insert two records to an almost empty DB...

Comment: It seems that other process has locked the table(rows) and you are trying to run other query that fails. Try to check innodb status with 'SHOW INNODB STATUS' after failing, there can be useful information or a query that is currently locks the row.

Comment: The SHOW INNODB STATUS log:
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 125, query id 1503 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
insert into profile_units (ProfileId, ActivityId) values (1, 2)
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 13 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 340 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `sadnaproject`.`profile` trx id 3AA lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0 - 
Does that makes any sense?

Comment: It says that one row is locked by another transaction. ...I see you found the problem.